# How to properly check if the button pressed is correct in multiple choice quiz HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, event-delegation

I'm wondering how to adapt this further, when I don't use All, it works for the first question. However, on the second question, the buttons don't work. Using All for some reason doesn't allow me to press the buttons at all. I do plan to add more questions to this.

I am very much a beginner at this as you can see.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  let correct = document.querySelector('.correct');
  correct.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    correct.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    document.querySelector('.feedback1').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
  });

  let incorrects = document.querySelectorAll('.incorrect');
  for (let i = 0; i < incorrects.length; i++) {
    incorrects[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      incorrects[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      document.querySelector('.feedback1').innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #20b2aa;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Marker Felt', fantasy;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.section {
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
}

.section:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  transition: color 2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.imgContainer {
  text-align: center;
}

.imgButton {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="header">
  <h1>Flag Quiz</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2 style="padding-top: 20px;">Multiple Choice Quiz</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="section">
    <h3>What country is this?</h3>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Flag_of_Lithuania.svg/640px-Flag_of_Lithuania.svg.png" width="40%">
  </div>
  <div class="imgButton">
    <button class="incorrect">Myanmar</button>
    <button class="incorrect">Latvia</button>
    <button class="correct">Lithuania</button>
    <button class="incorrect">Italy</button>
    <p class="feedback1"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <h3>What country is this?</h3>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Bandera_de_Espa%C3%B1a.svg/1200px-Bandera_de_Espa%C3%B1a.svg.png" width="40%">
  </div>
  <div class="imgButton">
    <button class="correct">Spain</button>
    <button class="incorrect">Portugal</button>
    <button class="incorrect">Mexico</button>
    <button class="incorrect">China</button>
    <p class="feedback1"></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I tried changing the correct answer checkers into the same format as the incorrect ones, however, that didn't work.

Comment: I highly recommend you to read into `data`-attributes rather than using classes (which are for CSS). Also, use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` which is comparably slower and poses security risks.

Comment: Oh thanks for the textContent tip, i just changed that. About the data-attributes, do i need to specify them in a css file to use?

Comment: `let correct = document.querySelector('.correct');` this only finds ONE not all like  let `correct = document.querySelectorAll('.correct');` to get that collection of nodes THUS, you are only adding the event listener to that first one.

Comment: @Benxsu ... Regarding the so far provided answers / approaches, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

I would choose [event-delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) where ...

- one initially does register the reference of a single handler-function to each container-/parent-element which contains all of a distinct question's answer-options/buttons ...
- one, within the mentioned handler-function, does query the element of the [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) matching selector of the targeted answer-button.

The handler then changes all of the related answer-buttons states, like rendering the correct feedback-text and setting certain button states like a button's background-color and even a button element's `disabled` state.

***Note***

The presented implementation explicitly uses the OP's `correct`/`incorrect` class-names by additionally classifying a final answer as `answered` and providing two additional rules to it ...

```
.correct.answered { background-color: green; }
.incorrect.answered { background-color: red; }
```

```js
function handleAnswerValidation({ target, currentTarget }) {
  // - event delegation ... part II.
  // - query the element of the closest matching
  //   selector of the targeted answer-button.
  const elmButton = target.closest('button');
  if (elmButton) {

    // - access the buttons classList property.
    const { classList } = elmButton;

    // - compute the correct feedback text/value
    //   according to the related, existing class name.
    const feedback = (
      (classList.contains('incorrect') && 'Incorrect') ||
      (classList.contains('correct') && 'Correct') ||
      ''
    );
    // - render the feedback text into the related element.
    currentTarget
      .querySelector('.feedback1')
      .textContent = feedback;

    // - query all current question's buttons and disable each.
    currentTarget
      .querySelectorAll('button')
      .forEach(elmButton => elmButton.disabled = true);

    // mark the pressed/clicked button as "answered".
    classList.add('answered');
  }
}

document
  // - event delegation ... part I.
  .querySelectorAll('.imgButton')
  // - register the reference of a single handler-function
  //   to each container-/parent-element which contains all
  //   of a distinct question's answer-options/buttons.
  .forEach(rootNode =>
    rootNode.addEventListener('click', handleAnswerValidation)
  );
```

```css
h1 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Marker Felt', fantasy;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #20b2aa;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.section {
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
}
.section:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  transition: color 2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.imgContainer {
  text-align: center;
}
.imgButton {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.correct.answered { background-color: green; }
.incorrect.answered { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<!-- Body -->
<div class="header">
  <h1>Flag Quiz</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2 style="padding-top: 20px;">Multiple Choice Quiz</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="section">
    <h3>What country is this?</h3>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Flag_of_Lithuania.svg/640px-Flag_of_Lithuania.svg.png" width="40%">
  </div>
  <div class="imgButton">
    <button class="incorrect">Myanmar</button>
    <button class="incorrect">Latvia</button>
    <button class="correct">Lithuania</button>
    <button class="incorrect">Italy</button>
    <p class="feedback1"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <h3>What country is this?</h3>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Bandera_de_Espa%C3%B1a.svg/1200px-Bandera_de_Espa%C3%B1a.svg.png" width="40%">
  </div>
  <div class="imgButton">
    <button class="correct">Spain</button>
    <button class="incorrect">Portugal</button>
    <button class="incorrect">Mexico</button>
    <button class="incorrect">China</button>
    <p class="feedback1"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you do not apply styles ona  button, you can simply use data-attributes. You also can select them in CSS with `[data-answer="correct"]`. Personally I would rename them instead of using `correct` and `incorrect` and use a boolean `true`/`false`.

You also do not need to iterate over all the buttons but could simply use `target` to select the clicked element.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const BUTTONS = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  BUTTONS.forEach(button =>
    button.addEventListener('click', function(element) {
      /* reads out the data-attribute of the clicked button and returns a boolean */
      let answer = (element.target.dataset.answer === 'true');
      /* gets the output element that is within the same block group of the clicked button */
      let output = element.target.closest('.imgButton').querySelector('output');
      
      /* changes the text of the output element */
      output.textContent = (answer) ? 'Correct!' : 'Incorrect';
      /* applies the a different CSS class to color the background */
      element.target.classList.add((answer) ? 'bg-green' : 'bg-red');
    })
  );
});
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #20b2aa;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Marker Felt', fantasy;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.section {
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
}

.section:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  transition: color 2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.imgContainer {
  text-align: center;
}

.imgButton {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bg-green {
  background-color: green;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="header">
  <h1>Flag Quiz</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2 style="padding-top: 20px;">Multiple Choice Quiz</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="section">
    <h3>What country is this?</h3>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Flag_of_Lithuania.svg/640px-Flag_of_Lithuania.svg.png" width="40%">
  </div>
  <div class="imgButton">
    <button data-answer="false">Myanmar</button>
    <button data-answer="false">Latvia</button>
    <button data-answer="true">Lithuania</button>
    <button data-answer="false">Italy</button>
    <output class="feedback"></output>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <h3>What country is this?</h3>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Bandera_de_Espa%C3%B1a.svg/1200px-Bandera_de_Espa%C3%B1a.svg.png" width="40%">
  </div>
  <div class="imgButton">
    <button data-answer="true">Spain</button>
    <button data-answer="false">Portugal</button>
    <button data-answer="false">Mexico</button>
    <button data-answer="false">China</button>
    <output class="feedback"></output>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow perfect. Thank you very much, seems these data-attributes are something work looking into! I change the 'Incorrect' and 'Correct' into the booleans as you recommended. Going from python to something like this is just so mind numbing :/...

Comment: Issue with Spain showing red when clicked here...

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thanks for pointing that out. I haven't switched the second block to true/false. Fixed the issue now